# Identifying a pattern only if occurring with another pattern

Tags: grep

I am trying to find a line that contains the word 'status' only if that same line contains any of the numbers written. I want a line to contain a specified number AND string

Example of the line I'm trying to find:

```
1929356 Query ..........'Status'......
```

```
grep '1929356\|1929357\|1929371' querydump.log | grep 'status' querydump.log
```

this is the line that I attempts to do this with. However, it gives me a bunch of lines starting with any of the #s "1929356 or 1929357 or 1929371" AND THEN unrelated Querys that contain the string 'status'

Comment: What is your input file and what output do you get and why isn't that output expected? `grep status` should not pick up `Status` (wrong case). Why do you pipe grep output into another grep command and still pass a file name to the 2nd grep? Try removing the file name from the 2nd grep. If that doesn't help, please [edit] your question and make a [mcve].

Comment: Perhaps `grep '\(1929356\|1929357\|1929371\) Query .* Status' querydump.log`?